# Calling two WCF services in one transaction. Both talk to the same database. Is MSDTC is the only option

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, msdtc

I have a WCF Service ServiceA.

That in turn has to call two individual WCF services ServiceB and ServiceC which do two different things, but if the call to ServiceC fails I want to rollback what ServiceB did.

I did implement it using TransactionScope (I am using EF 6.0) however without enabling MSDTC it is not working. Is there a workaround for this? I really do not want to go through the MSDTC route because I am afraid that would cause a lot of performance issues and the web admins are strongly against it.

Comment: Hmm - you need a certain service but you don't want to use the standard component that provides it. Write your own?

Comment: What DB do you use? Version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a distributed transaction, because your transaction contains cross boundary participants. To the best of my knowledge, the only solution for a distributed transaction in windows platform is MSDTC, there is no way around this.

I would, however, recommend that you try to seek a more eventual consistent solution, rather than strictly transactional, because your solution will most likely perform and scale better. Granted, you will have to deal with special cases where your data is not consistent, which will lead to more complex code.

From my experience, it will be worth it, but its up to you.